# How to take a backup in lan?

Tags: .net, merge, backup, lan

I am working in one company there are **15 people** working i have to **merge** their work in my PC everyday.

Its very time consuming can you provide some good resource which could work in **LAN** with good performance i am sorry if i have added this question on a wrong place but i have no ideas about it my colleague told me that there are some free resources but i don't find any when i search on Google thanks in advance....

Comment: did you try using some svn like Tortoise SVN, etc?

Comment: No thanks for reply i didn't tried anything can you provide me some refrence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any subversion software like Tortoise SVN or GIT..

You need to checkout the code from the domain the code is hosted upon.. Every colleague of yours will commit their code on the same domain and you can use "SVN merge" option to merge their code.

You can read more the following link:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseSVN

Comment: I need this one in offline as well not only at domain

Comment: Then there is a software called "WinMerge".. It lets you compare two files.. Although you will still have to merge it manually

Comment: and what about automatically?